# Clicking ContextMenu-option only triggers RelayCommand once

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Each ListBox item has a `ContextMenu` "Kick" option. It does trigger the `CanKickPlayer()` method when I right-click the first `ListBox` item for the first time, but never again if I repeat the process on the same or a different `ListBox` item. Questions:

1. How to do so `CanKickPlayer()` triggers every time I choose the `ContextMenu` "Kick" option?
2. Why is the passed parameter in `CanKickPlayer()` method null?

[image]

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="ContextMenuTriggeredOnce.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="200">

    <GroupBox Header="Players">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Players}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlayer}">
            <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Kick" Command="{Binding KickPlayerCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedPlayer}" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListBox.ContextMenu>
        </ListBox>
    </GroupBox>

</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
        DataContext = MainViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Players { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    private string _selectedPlayer;
    public string SelectedPlayer
    {
        get => _selectedPlayer;
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            SetProperty(ref _selectedPlayer, value);
        }
    }

    private readonly RelayCommand _kickPlayerCommand;
    public ICommand KickPlayerCommand => _kickPlayerCommand;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Players.Add("Player1");
        Players.Add("Player2");

        _kickPlayerCommand = new RelayCommand(OnKickPlayer, CanKickPlayer);
    }

    private void OnKickPlayer(object command)
    {
        Players.Remove(command.ToString());
        _kickPlayerCommand.InvokeCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    private bool CanKickPlayer(object command)
    {
        return command != null;
    }
}
```

**BaseViewModel.cs**

```cs
public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            field = newValue;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**RelayCommand.cs**

```cs
class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _executeAction;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecuteAction;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> executeAction, Func<object, bool> canExecuteAction)
    {
        _executeAction = executeAction;
        _canExecuteAction = canExecuteAction;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _executeAction(parameter);
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecuteAction?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
    public void InvokeCanExecuteChanged() => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Comment: CanExecuteChanged is only called again if the view gets notified it was changed. So you need to call ```RelayCommand.InvokeCanExecuteChanged``` in your view model to notify reevaluation it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It seems to work if I put _kickPlayerCommand.InvokeCanExecuteChanged() below SetProperty(ref _selectedPlayer, value) in the SelectedPlayer property the second time I open the context menu, but the first time it is still disabled and the parameter passed to CanKickPlayer is null, and I do not understand why?

Comment: Maybe the initial value for selected player is null, so SetProperty is not reached?

Comment: Hmm. SelectedPlayer does have a value, but the command parameter in CanKickPlayer(object command) is null the first time, for some strange reason. Very strange...

Comment: Seems to be a known-not-yet-fixed bug in WPF. See duplicate. Why the suggested hack to swap the binding declarations works is unclear; I would not rely on that as a fix, as there's nothing documented that would ensure it would always do what you want (order of declarations isn't supposed to matter at all). Instead, either explicitly force the command to update by calling `InvokeCanExecuteChanged` when the dependent property changes, or use the attached-property/behavior-based fix linked in the duplicate's answer.

Comment: Very interesting. I did not expect it to be such a big of an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the CommandParameter before Command.

```
                <MenuItem Header="Kick" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedPlayer}" Command="{Binding KickPlayerCommand}" />
```

(I don't use the Command pattern. I prefer using the Click event and from the Click event handler calling a function in the ViewModel. If I need to disable the menu item, I use a bool property in the ViewModel and bind that to the IsEnabled property on the menu item.)